# Suppress DebugWrite : "(CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded .Cannot find or open the PDB file."

Tags: windows-10-universal, debug-symbols

In universal App , output window I see these kind of annoying message about built-in/framework libraries(not my code):
"(CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data...Debug_ARM.xx\System.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file."

How can I suppress this? I have enabled Just my code. Also tried Optimize Code(Proj properties->Build). These logs makes it diffcult to read my own debug writes in the output window.

Comment: Just right-click the Output window and untick "Module Load Messages".  There ought to be some more in that dialog that you find annoying if this matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> Module Load Messages -> Off

It works for me.